# Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the vwap value over a minute period. I have extracted the values, but get the above error message when trying to input the values into a data frame. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import yfinance as yf


stock_1="HOMB"
stock_1 = yf.Ticker(stock_1)
history = stock_1.history("1m")
past=history.head()
dividends=past['Dividends']
stock_split=past['Stock Splits']

history=past.drop('Dividends',1).drop('Stock Splits',1)

df=pd.DataFrame(history, columns=['volume','high','low'] )

today = date.today()

v=history.loc[today,"Volume"]
#print(v)
h=history.loc[today,"High"]
l=history.loc[today,"Low"]
print(v,h,l)
vdiff=v[1:2]-v[0:1]
hdiff=h[1:2]-h[0:1]
ldiff=l[1:2]-l[0:1]
v=vdiff
h=hdiff
l=ldiff

df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([v,h,l]), columns=['volume','high','low'] )


df['vwap_pandas'] = (df.v*(df.h+df.l)/2).cumsum() / df.v.cumsum()

print(df['vwap_pandas'])
```

Comment: The way that slices work in Python is that the upper limit of the slice is not included in what you get. `[0,1]` is therefore the same as `[0]`, etc.

Comment: You mean [0:1] right?  And it's not exactly the same right, since it returns a list from with [0] in it?  So more like v[0:1] is the same as [v[0]]

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a typo. `v[0:1]` is the same as `[v[0]]`.